# SQL Query to find the Row with first change of data

Tags: sql, sql-server

| UniqueId | ITEM | DATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 2022-01-01 |
| 2 | A | 2022-01-02 |
| 3 | B | 2022-01-03 |
| 4 | B | 2022-01-04 |
| 5 | A | 2022-01-05 |
| 6 | A | 2022-01-06 |
| 7 | B | 2022-01-07 |
| 8 | B | 2022-01-08 |
| 9 | A | 2022-01-09 |
| 10 | A | 2022-01-10 |
| 11 | A | 2022-01-11 |

I have above table where the item is changing from A to B and then B to A (etc).
The the most recent item in the table based on the date is A (the last row).

I need to find the date on which this last item (A) was started to be in effect.

So in this case the item A was in effect from 2022-01-09 onwards (UniqueId 9).

How can I find the UniqueId or the date of item A, where it got changed to be in effect (Row 9)?

Thank you.

Comment: Did I understand correctly? You want to know dateTime of the last time a row modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting a flag using a comparison of current item with previous item in time, using `LAG()` is indeed the way.

But it's absolutely sufficient to get the highest date and highest unique (as both are sorted ascending together) where the obtained flag is 1:

```
WITH
-- your input
indata(UniqueId,ITEM,DATE) AS (
          SELECT 1,'A',DATE '2022-01-01'
UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A',DATE '2022-01-02'
UNION ALL SELECT 3,'B',DATE '2022-01-03'
UNION ALL SELECT 4,'B',DATE '2022-01-04'
UNION ALL SELECT 5,'A',DATE '2022-01-05'
UNION ALL SELECT 6,'A',DATE '2022-01-06'
UNION ALL SELECT 7,'B',DATE '2022-01-07'
UNION ALL SELECT 8,'B',DATE '2022-01-08'
UNION ALL SELECT 9,'A',DATE '2022-01-09'
UNION ALL SELECT 10,'A',DATE '2022-01-10'
UNION ALL SELECT 11,'A',DATE '2022-01-11'
)
-- real query starts here; replace following comma with "WITH"
,
w_change_ind AS (
  SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN LAG(item) OVER(ORDER BY date) <> item
      THEN 1
      ELSE 0
    END AS chg_ind
  FROM indata
)
SELECT
  MAX(uniqueid) AS uqid
, MAX(date)     AS dt
FROM w_change_ind
 WHERE chg_ind=1
;
-- out  uqid |     dt     
-- out ------+------------
-- out     9 | 2022-01-09
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *,
        last_value(item) over (order by "date") as last_item,
        lag(item) over (order by "date") as prev_item
    from T
)
select
    max(case when item = last_item and item <> prev_item then "date" end) as max_date
from data;
```

or

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case when item <> lag(item)        over (order by "date")
              and item =  last_value(item) over (order by "date")
             then 1 end as flag
    from T
)
select max("date") as last_transition_date
from data
where flag = 1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=bd5f6398c0167d74c26a67fafac5225e

Supposing you need all the data:

```
with data as (
    select *,
        case when item <> lag(item)        over (order by "date")
              and item =  last_value(item) over (order by "date")
             then 1 end as flag
    from T
)
select *,
    max(case when flag = 1 then "date" end) over () as last_transition_date
from data;
```

Comment: Thank you for this solution !! this  fits my requirement

Answer (score -1):

Based on your description, this is one way to do what you want.

```
select top 1 * from table1
where item ='A'
order by uniqueid desc
```

If this is not what you want, then you will have to provide additional information.

Comment: he wants clearly line number 9, which your query doesn't provide

Comment: @nbk, corrected by changing to uniqueid.

Comment: You're still assuming that last item will always be A. And the assumption that id values are in ascending order very likely a bad idea especially when the date column is present.